# How do I run npm command in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

so I have installed node.js to my local computer, and trying to use `npm` command in Visual Studio Code. However whenever I try, such as `npm run start` for React, I get error saying 
: 'npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file 

 The weird thing is that when I run the command in my local terminal it works fine. It only gives that error when trying to use it on Visual Studio Code. What do you think I've done wrong?

Comment: Can you add information on what OS your are using.

Comment: Vscode has a terminal. Ensure you have node installed in any of the terminals used by Vscode.

Comment: You need to restart after installing something that makes changes to your PATH.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try opening Visual Studio Code from command in local terminal.

- Open command window
- Write *code* and press enter, it will open Visual Studio Code
- Then try running your npm commands form Visual Studio Code. Hopefully it will work.